# Android emulator won't load past the "android" load screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've seen this question around stack overflow. Tried various solutions and none work for me. Lowered the RAM size, changed VM Heap size, made sure I have Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) installed but nothing works. Some people recommend Genymotion but I think there's an annual fee.

Only the original AVD that came with Android Studio works, NEXUS 5X API 24.
I added a new Nexus 6 API 21 AVD and it doesn't load past "android" load screen. I made a custom AVD and it doesn't load as well pass "android" load screen.

All 3 AVD's run on x86 CPU/ABI and 3GB size on disk.

The only difference is the NEXUS 5X AVD uses Nougat Android 7.0 x86 while the custom AVD and Nexus 6 uses Lollipop Android 5.0 x86 because I want to develop app with Screen Capture.

So what can I do to make the emulators work?

Comment: Please edit your question to include OS, CPU, RAM memory and how long did you wait after creating a AVD for it to connect as well as SDK version.

Comment: Well actually only AVD's with "Play Store" checked work, the rest don't work. How do I get a "Play Store" check on my AVD's that I create?